# I'm using PHP for quick and dirty scripts - is it worth switching?

Tags: php, console, window

I'm good at PHP and have quite a lot of experience in it. I can write commonly used scripts for the Desktop for moving files around, making backups of projects very quickly and comfortably.

As I'm using Windows I cannot take advantage of a specialized language like bash.

- Is it worth learning another scripting language for everyday tasks in the console?
- What would be some good options for the Windows platform? Maybe even general-purpose languages like Python or Ruby?

Comment: Why not just get the PHP distro. and run against it on windows?

Comment: Learning Ruby would definitely be worth it in my opinion.

Comment: Windows Command Line: http://commandwindows.com/

Answer (score 2):

For this sort of task on Windows I'd recommend learning [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell).

Answer (score 1):

You can set up bash on windows using cygwin

On windows, CMD or powershell are the ways to go.

Both python and ruby are available for windows, but those are higher level languages.  for very down-and-dirty things id learn CMD first

Answer (score 0):

Why are you considering switching to Python, Ruby, etc?  Windows does have it's own command scripting language, though not nearly as robust as bash.  PHP implementations on Windows are well-maintained and useful.

Since you are experienced with PHP i'm not sure why you would want to use something else?